# Ho do I access and control fancyBox in parent window from inside an iframe with Fancybox 3

Tags: html, iframe, video.js, fancybox-3

I am not really a programmer, merely an HTML coder who has been cannibalising scripts for many years without really being able to quite understand what I'm doing.  I have finally hit an impasse.

I am using Fancybox 3 to open a responsive iFrame into which I am loading an HTML5 video which is set to autoplay.  All works great except that the iFrame is a) initially cropped at the bottom (a fault which is instantly fixed by slightly resizing the browser window) and b) does not adjust to the size of the content when the window is reduced in size.  I get white space opening up under the video.

The Fancybox 3 documentation suggests using this piece of script in order to achieve what I'm after but no explanation of how exactly to implement it.  I guess the author assumes I know more than I do about these things, which seems fair enough.

This is the snippet of script:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().update();
```

I'm guessing this would solve all my problems.  Can anyone show me how to implement it?

The page in question is here: [test page](http://olivercherer.co.uk/dev/audi3/team-page2.html).

The Fancybox 3 documentation is [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe).

If I have asked this question badly please let me know as I am a newbie here.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

The `Iframed page` demo on homepage does exactly what are you looking for. See source code of http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/iframe.html for clues.

For example, this link would close fancyBox:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">Dismiss</a>
```